# How to build Wix Toolset 3.10 installer on tfs

Tags: c#, tfs, wix, wix3

Previously I have been using [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2006/03/15/552413.aspx) method to build msi's on our tfs-server. Now I have upgraded to wix 3.10 and I can no longer find a wix.targets file. I also cannot find any information pointing out why it has been removed.

Does anyone know if this approach has been deprecated, and if so, what is the preferred method to build on TFS?

Do I just need to change the wix 3.8 targets file?

edit:
I found a wix.ca.targets file in the SDK folder, but it does not seem to be quite the same. At least it does not work out of the box for me.

Comment: If your build server has access to the Nuget servers then use the wix nuGet package in your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current documentation is here: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/daily_builds.html.

Wix.targets ships with WiX v3.10. It's installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x` (on a 64-bit system) and available in wix310-binaries.zip in the `bin` subdirectory.